# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with REACTJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new with reactjs.

This is what I am trying

```
class EventDemo extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.getStarWars()
        this.state = {}
    }

    getStarWars = ()=> axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/people')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                names: res.data.results
            })

        })
    
    
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.names);
        
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.names.map(function(e){
                    return <li>{e.name}</li>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But This following error i am getting

[image: error]

What I am doing wrong here ? It supposed to work .

Comment: Just add `names: []` to the `this.state` object inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,you shouldn't call your this.getStarWars() function inside the constructor, it is a very bad practice and could cause you troubles, http calls in React component should be generally called from the componentDidMount function.

However the issue in this case is another one,you haven't given an initial value to this.state.names, so when the component tries to do the initial render it fails because the names are undefined since the initial render appens before the http call is resolved

You code should be fixed like this:

```
class EventDemo extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = { names:[] }
    }

   componentDidMount(){
      this.getStarWars()
   }


    getStarWars = ()=> axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/people')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                names: res.data.results
            })

        })



    render() {
        console.log(this.state.names);

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.names.map(function(e){
                    return <li>{e.name}</li>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: really appreciate the help

Comment: no problem! I had the same troubles as you when I first started out using react :)